# Dumb question about encoding negative two's complement into 16-bit machine instruction

Tags: java, binary, bit-manipulation

If I want to encode a signed two's complement negative # say -7 into the offset5 (last 5 bits) of a 16-bit machine instruction, can I simply do this? (Assuming I'm using Java)

```
int num = -7;
num = num & 0b11111;
```

Comment: Yes, but make sure that the value is in bound of a 5 bit signed int then. So if num would be - 32 then the last 5 bit would be b'00000. So actually encoding 0 with this way.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll use an asset to ensure value is in that range. Much appreciated.